# Array in dropdown (Handsontable)

Tags: javascript, arrays, drop-down-menu, handsontable

I want to put an array data in a dropdown with Handsontable. So, I created a little array like this :

```
var array_dropdown = ['Hello','test','lison','flag'];
```

And here is my HOT :

```
var container = document.getElementById('tab_traitement');
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: data_traitement,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    rowHeaders: false,
    colHeaders: false,
    contextMenu: true,
    height: 300,
    width: 810,
    colWidths: [200, 200, 200, 200],
    cells: function(row, col, prop) {
        var cellProperties = {};

        if ([0].indexOf(row) !== -1 && col >= 0) {
            cellProperties.readOnly = true;
        }
        return cellProperties;
    },
    columns: [{}, {}, {}, {
        type: 'dropdown',
        source: [array_dropdown] //Here, I'm trying to get the array data
    }]

});
```

[image: Here is what I get on my web page]

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: pls go through javascript tutorials at w3schools.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `source` option you don't need `[]`. This will make the array two-dimensional, as `array_dropdown` is already an `array`.

```
source: array_dropdown // Don't need `[]` here
```